# SNMP Make All OID's Public?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I have been attempting to access different OID's with no luck and significant research has lead me to believe that snmp is just configured to protect these parts of the system and I simply don't have access. How do I change the configuration to allow access to all OID's?
Or, how do I create a user who requires no authentication and no encryption (no priv)?

Comment: It's all about agent configuration and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @LexLi yes I understand, how do I configure it though?